# How to configure Tomcat instance fail over setup with Apache load balancer?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, cluster-computing, mod-proxy-balancer

How can I configure the Tomcat instance fail over with Apache load balancer?

Currently, as per my setup,  there are 3 Tomcat instances handling requests but if in case, any instance fails then also load balancer keeps sending requests to it and those requests are getting failed.

I need help in configuring the load balancer in such a way that it gets the status as failed and forward requests to an another available instance. Also,  when instance gets ready then again it starts forwarding requests to it.

Comment: Would you show the relevant part of your existing configuration? That might be helpful to readers, and in any case will show you're not looking for someone to do a whole piece of work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!                                                                                                      workers.properties file                                                               worker.list = dbloadbalancer, status                                         worker.worker1.port = 8202                                                      worker.worker1.host = 172.20.185.49                                  worker.worker1.type = ajp13                                                   worker.worker1. lbfactor = 1                                             worker.worker2.port = 8200                                                      worker.worker2.host = 172.20.185.49                               worker.worker2.type = ajp13                                                   worker.worker2.lbfactor = 1                                               worker.dbloadbalancer.type = lb                                                    worker.dbloadbalancer.balance_workers = worker1, worker 2                                                                         worker.dbloadbalancer.sticky_session = 0                                         worker.jkstatus.type = status                                                             Please suggest on failover setup.